# Creating a function that concatenates two strings

Tags: c

Create a function that concatenates two strings
The function should be created based on the following criteria

1. The putchar keyword should be used
2. The prototype must be char *_strcat(char *dest, char *src);
3. The function should add a terminating null value at the end of dest
4. The function should return a pointer to dest.

The function below finds the end of the src string and appends it to dest string.
I tried it out with my main.c file and got
World!Hello  instead of Hello World!

```
void concatenate(char* str1, char* str2) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    // Find the end of the first string
    while (str1[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }

    // Append the second string to the end of the first string
    while (str2[j] != '\0') {
        str1[i] = str2[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    // Add a null terminator to the end of the concatenated string
    str1[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `I tried it out with my main.c file and got World!Hello instead of Hello World!` Seems like you flipped `str1` and `str2` in your main.

Comment: We need to see your `main` function that calls `concatenate`. You may have the args reversed. Or, if you do: `char dst[] = "Hello"; concatenate(dst,"World!");` then you have UB (undefined behavior) because `dst` does _not_ have enough space to contain the combined string. You'd need (e.g.): `char dst[30] = "Hello"; concatenate(dst,"World!");`

Comment: Kindly show the main function. 
I believe you misplaced the arguments while calling ```concatenate```. Other than that, your function doesn't do what it's supposed to do, (at least, according to the assignment) but:                        
```1.``` You do not check whether the first string is large enough to hold ```str2```. ```2.``` You do not check whether one or both of the pointers are pointing to valid memory, or in other words, are not ```NULL```.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment has problems:

> *Create a function that concatenates two strings*.

This statement is not precise enough: should it allocate a new string or concatenate the second string at the end of the first string like `strcat()`?

> *The function should be created based on the following criteria*.

I would rather write: The function should meet the following requirements.

> *The `putchar` keyword should be used*.

This is a most ridiculous requirement! `putchar` is not a *keyword*, but a macro (an a function) defined in `<stdio.h>`. Using it in a user function is feasible, but tricky, not something newbies should be required to try and certainly not something any programmer should do.

> *The prototype must be `char *_strcat(char *dest, char *src);`*

This requirement is bogus:

- the identifier is a reserved word (it starts with an `_`). `my_strcat` or `concat_string` would be better choices
- at least `src` should be declared `const char *src`. And it would indicate that the function likely behaves like `strcat`, or both arguments should be `const` qualified and the function should allocate memory.

> The function should add a terminating null value at the end of dest.

This is implicit if the result is to be used as a C string.

> The function should return a pointer to `dest`.

At last an indication regarding the expected semantics: the same as `strcat`.

Your implementation is almost correct, except for this:

- the name is not as specified
- the argument names are not `dest` and `src`
- you should use `size_t` for the type of `i` and `j`
- you must return `dest`.

Regarding your observations, you did not post the full program, but it is likely you passed the arguments in the wrong order and/or the destination array that contains `Hello`  is not long enough to receive the concatenated string.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *my_strcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

#ifdef putchar
    // just using the putchar identifier for fun
#endif

    // Find the end of the first string
    while (dest[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }

    // Append the second string to the end of the first string
    while (src[j] != '\0') {
        dest[i] = src[j];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    // Add a null terminator to the end of the concatenated string
    dest[i] = '\0';

    // return a pointer to dest.
    return dest;
}

int main() {
    char hello[20] = "Hello ";
    char world[] = "World!";

    printf("%s\n", my_strcat(hello, world));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I know why you used preprocessor directives ifdef and define?

Comment: I used int to declare i and j as they will serve as counters for the iteration. As you know, putchar can only display a character at a time. But why do we use size_t instead?